# FontAwesome change default prefix

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want to change the default prefix to Font Awesome Regular
So tried doing

```
fontawesome.config = {
  familyPrefix: "far"
};
```

But I still have to do an "far" prefix to make it work

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
import FontAwesomeIcon from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import faCalendar from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular/faCalendar";
import faSquare from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular/faSquare";

fontawesome.config = {
  familyPrefix: "far"
};

fontawesome.library.add(faCalendar, faSquare);

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
    Favorite beverage: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="calendar" /> //does not work
    Icon from regular: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["far", "square"]} /> //works
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/40v5jk6no7

Comment: I think it's expected behaviour. Default prefix for FontAwesome is `fa` and you're changing it to `far`. So `far-square` works, but `fa-square` and `square` does not.

Comment: By the way I'm amazed how a simple iconic font evolved in the past years into something bigger, something that has it's own [API](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/font-awesome-api) 

Comment: Is there a way I can make <FontAwesomeIcon icon="calendar" /> work? I was under the assumption, this would change the default and now  could use the icons from "  Font Awesome Regular " with no prefix

Comment: I don't know. Have you tried `fontawesome.config = {
  familyPrefix: ""
};` ?

Comment: Will try that. But I need to be able to make Font Awesome Regular as default and use <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" /> and make it work. Now it takes Font Awesome Solid as default

Comment: Did you figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the desired behavior is unattainable via FontAwesome component configuration.

After source code analysis I can say that an icon with prefix `fa` is resolved as an icon belonging to `font-family: solid` and `'fa'` prefix is hardcoded here ([fontawesome/index.es.js](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/advanced-options/use-with-node-js/fontawesome/index.es.js#L1560)):

```
function findIconDefinition(params) {
  var _params$prefix = params.prefix,
      prefix = _params$prefix === undefined ? 'fa' : _params$prefix,
      iconName = params.iconName;

  if (!iconName) return;

  return iconFromMapping(library.definitions, prefix, iconName) || iconFromMapping(namespace.styles, prefix, iconName);
}
```

You still have an option to customize source code of the component for your project (I mean you can just replace `prefix = _params$prefix === undefined ? 'fa' : _params$prefix` with `prefix = _params$prefix === undefined ? 'far' : _params$prefix`) but I don't recommend this approach since it looks like a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me.